# SQL error ORDER BY clause Not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

ORDER BY  clause  Not working with  Union, aliases(as) getting some error

**Messenger table**

```
       mid    senderid   receiverid   message   
      ---------------------------------------
        4       100       200          hi
        3       200       100          hello
        2       100       200          hi
        1       100       200          hi
```

**select statement**

```
  select senderid as new_id from messenger  where  receiverid=200
  union 
  select  receiverid from messenger  where  senderid =200
  order by mid  desc
```

**error**

```
   #1054 - Unknown column 'mid' in 'order clause'
```

I don't know what  mistake I made, help me  Thanks in advance

Comment: When UNION only select list items may be used in ORDER BY. (Try UNION ALL instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your united  result you have not a mid  column
You have only `new_id`
you should add

```
select mid, senderid as new_id 
from messenger  where  receiverid=200
union 
select mid, receiverid 
from messenger  where  senderid =200
order by mid  desc
```

or avoid union just using a single query

```
select case when senderid = 200 then reciverid else senderid as new_id 
from messenger  
where  receiverid=200 or senderid = 200
order by mid
```

Comment: sir  its working but how can I use distinct for ignore multiple values help me

Comment: @CforCODE . . . I'm surprised you accepted this answer.  Your question implies that you want one column rather than two.  More importantly, this does not remove duplicates.

Comment: @scaisEdge yes I know that and solved   my  issue thanks again

Comment: @scaisEdge  sir please help me  for this quetion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348120/mysql-php-insert-into-3-different-queries-tables-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `union`?

```
select (case when receiverid = 200 then senderid else receiverid end) as new_id
from messenger m
where 200 in (receiverid, senderid)
group by new_id
order by min(mid) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have mid field in your union query, so either make it

```
 select senderid as new_id from messenger  where  receiverid=200
  union 
  select  receiverid as new_id from messenger  where  senderid =200
  order by new_id  desc
```

or to

```
 select mid,senderid as new_id from messenger  where  receiverid=200
  union 
  select  mid,receiverid as new_id from messenger  where  senderid =200
  order by mid  desc
```

Comment: Mid is a _column_, not a field.

Comment: @jarlh just different terminology, field=column, record=row

Comment: Well, not according to the ISO/ANSI SQL specification. (Perhaps as in the Excel documentation?)